# Combining values in group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have another group by question.

Values in my table can be as follows:

```
name1
name2
name1;name1
name1
name2;name2;name2
```

I need to get counts for this field combining the values. Sorry, it's a little hard to explain, but basically I need to combine into one total whether a value is 'name1' or 'name1;name1' or 'name1;name1;name1' (can be repeated any number of times). So the result would be

```
name1  - 3 
name2  - 2
```

Thank  you.

Comment: One table-cell (row, column) literally has 'name1;name1' as it's value?  I'd expect you have to count `';'` in that case, probably by replacement with a different width string...

Comment: do you have a separator at all, or is it implied

Answer (score 0):

if all your values are like ones in your example, try this:

```
select
    left(t.col, 5), count(*)
from <your table> as t
group by left(t.col, 5)
```

Comment: not all values are like this, but if they are, they would be separated by semicolon. However there could be some legit semicolons, meaning, that whatever follows is not exactly as whatever is before. E.g: name1;name2 - the semicolon is part of value and not a separator

Answer (score 0):

this allows different name's length

```
DECLARE @STUFF AS TABLE
(MyField nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @Stuff VALUES ('fred;1234')
INSERT INTO @Stuff VALUES ('fred;fred')
INSERT INTO @Stuff VALUES ('bib;')
INSERT INTO @Stuff VALUES ('bob;')
INSERT INTO @Stuff VALUES ('bib;bib')
INSERT INTO @Stuff VALUES ('steve;steve')
```

/*Add a Default ; to prevent field with none*/

```
UPDATE @STUFF  SET MyField = MyField + ';'

select
    left(t.myfield, charindex(';', T.myfield)), count(*)
from @Stuff as t
group by left(t.myfield, CHARINDEX(';', T.myfield))



UPDATE @STUFF  SET MyField = LEFT(MyField, LEN(MyField)-1)
```

/*Remove last character, which is the ; we added*/

Comment: if the value is not repeated, there is no semicolon at the end. So what it does for me is it returns (per your example) 2 separate counts for 'bib' and for all 'bib;bib's

Comment: I changed my answer to account for that

Comment: the first 2 rows (from your example) get combined into 1. They can only be combined if there is a repeated value. So 'fred', 'fred;fred' and 'fred;fred;fred' should be combined, but 'fred', 'fred;steve', 'fred;freddy' are all different